# Entering bounty message looks strange

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, information-display, bounty-remarks

I just submitted a bounty on a question and I typed a custom reason. Here is what I saw:[image: bounty display problem]

I know that I typed the bounty message correctly, because it [displays properly in the actual question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361424/swing-remote-desktop-exception). This is only a problem with the display of the bounty message submission box. I am using Firefox 24.0. Notice that not only is what I've typed corrupted, but also the leftmost characters in the number of characters remaining and the *Enter a custom...* header and the *Are you sure...* message and the *Back* button are also cut off.